# Load url without url change

Tags: java, url, playframework, controller

Given I have two different application servers. One is my play application and one is another application that is running on the same server.

A user opens a link in the play application that redirects to an url from the other application.

```
public class DocumentController extends Controller {
    public Result open(String id) {
        String url = generateURL(id);
        return redirect(url);
    }
}
```

- play framework application URL: http://localhost/document?id=1
- other application URL: http://localhost/document?internalid=adsf34rt3j43h43bn34jje3bsfdf29&otherinternalid=sdfne9239245ngdh

At the moment if the user opens the first URL he get redirected to the other URL and then sees this other URL in his browser. I want the URL to stay the same as the first URL but still load and show the content of the second URL. The user should only see the first URL in his browser navigation bar.

A solution should be integrated into the existing controller. What I'm looking for is a replacement for "redirect(url)". I'm thinking of something like "load(url)" or loadInFrame(url).

Is this possible?

---

## Solution as suggested by [rorschach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3350516/rorschach)

It's not quite like I imagined it but it works :)

I have add a new view:

```
@(url: String)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="@url"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And instead of redirecting to an URL I now render this new view with the given URL in the iframe:

```
return ok(iframeView.render(url));
```

Comment: For sure, just load it in an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `<iframe>` to your page which loads that site or use a more fancy-pants solution - do a request for that other side in JavaScript and then replace the full content of your page with that one.

EDIT: (after commenting)

I see you've completely changed the premise of the question. Oh well..

- return your own page in the Controller with the URL of that site in an `<iframe>`
- request the HTML content of that site in your Controller and stuff it into your own page.
- return your own page, load the other site with JS and replace the content
- make this unnecessarily complicated and start messing around with the web server's configuration do have it do a redirect on its level

Comment: This question is for the play framework. If I want a solution with javascript I would just do it. But still, thanks that you tried to help.

Comment: @Spen, Have you yourself gone through Play's documentation to find a solution to your question? If you had I'm sure you would've already found out that there isn't one because we're talking about front-end code - plain HTML, CSS, JS. Especially since you're talking about some other page somewhere else on the internet/intranet.

You can write templates to render pages server-side with Play (like any proper framework) and yes, you can also, conceivably, do what you want by requesting that site in your backend code and then rendering it *again* on the server-side but common sense tells you..

Comment: @Spen .. that this is a job for either an `<iframe>` or JavaScript. There's no reason to be snarky about this. And to add - even if you want to do it server-side you're still going to end up writing HTML because that's what this is.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear. I edited it to make more clear what I'm asking. Yes, I did read the documentation and didn't found anything. Otherwise I wouldn't ask a question on Stackoverflow. Just because it's not in the documentation doesn't mean anything at all. Therefore I'm asking if this is possible. If you are suggesting that this is not possible within the play framework than "No, this is not possible, because xy" would be a acceptable answer.